# how we can use in Laravel Jquery onchange element in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

```
<script>
    $('#brand_id').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var brand_id =  e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/product_id?brand_id =' + brand_id, function(data));
        //success data
        $.each(data, function(upload_form, product_cat){
            $('product_category').empty();
            $('product_category').append('<option value="'+ product_cat.id +'">'+ product_cat.product_hierarchy +'</option>');
        });

    });
```

Above is my Jquery code check this and point out me what is the problem.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{action('BrandController@upload_csv')}}" method="post">
    Brand Code
    <select name="brand_id" id="brand_id" Select="" class="form-control">
      <option value="">--Select Brand Code--</option>
      <?php foreach ($brands as $row) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $row->brand_id ?>"><?= $row->brand_name ?></option>

      <?php } ?>

    </select>
    Product Id
    <select name="product_category" id="product_category"   Select="" class="form-control">

    </select>

    Status
    <select name="status" Select="" class="form-control">
      <option value="">--Select Product Status--</option>

      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>

    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?= csrf_token(); ?>">
    Upload Valid csv file
    <input type="file" name="csv" required class="form-control">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

This is my form. in the form there is a select in which onchange element i want to show sub categories in next select. Below is my Route file code.

Route::get('/product_id', function(){
    $brand_id = Input::get('brand_id');

```
$product_id = product_hierarchy::where('bcategory_code','=',1)->get();

return Response::json($product_id);
```

});

Comment: What's the problem ? Which version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: laravel 5.2 Jquery not working will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Laravel 5.2` we have to pass the `csrf` token to execute the request.

just try like this...

```
<script>
        $('#brand_id').on('change',function(e){
            console.log(e);
            var brand_id =  e.target.value;

            //ajax
            $.get('/product_id?brand_id =' + brand_id,{"_token":$("input[name='_token']").val()}, function(data));
            //success data
            $.each(data, function(upload_form, product_cat){
                $('product_category').empty();
                $('product_category').append('<option value="'+ product_cat.id +'">'+ product_cat.product_hierarchy +'</option>');
            });

        });
</script>
```

I just add this line of code to your get request:

```
{ "_token" : $("input[name='_token']").val() }
```

Good Luck.. Happy Coding!!!

**Edited**

For detailed information about this you can found on the below linked tutorials:

[Laravel CRUD Using jQuery AJAX PART – 1](http://www.javascripthive.info/laravel/laravel-crud-using-jquery-ajax-part-1/)

[Laravel CRUD Using jQuery AJAX PART – 2](http://www.javascripthive.info/laravel/laravel-crud-using-jquery-ajax-part-2/)